# Flatten a deeply nested Collection

Tags: java, recursion, nested-lists

Given an Object of Type `<T>`, containing a set of `Set<T>` Objects (see example below). I'm trying to flatten the nested Sets into a single collection. Came across TreeTraverser (guava library) but unsure if it's ideal solution here.

```
Example

public class Tweet{
  int id;
  String message;
  DateTime date;
  Set<Tweet> replies;
}

Traverse the nested replies Set and place it in a collection;


for(Tweet a : tweets.replies){
  ...
 for(Tweet b : a.replies){
      ...
     for(Tweet c: b.replies){
       //soo on
     }

 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a defined depth to the recursion?

Comment: Can these point back to each other?  If not, then `TreeTraverser` should work great here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use recursion?

--DFS collection

```
public void collect(Set<Tweet> tweets, List<Tweet> collector)
{
     for (Tweet tweet: tweets)
     {
          collector.add(tweet); 
          if (tweet.replies != null)
             collect(tweet.replies, collector);
     }

}
```

Edited for completeness. 
You can also use TreeTraverser but it's a somewhat obscure Guava feature imo:

```
TreeTraverser<Tweet> traverser = new TreeTraverser<Tweet>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Tweet> children(Tweet root) {
        return root.replies;        }
};

List<Tweet> allTweets = new ArrayList<Tweet> (traverser.breadthFirstTraversal(root))
```

Comment: No. Just pass it the replies from the root node. Let 'tweet' be your root tweet List<Tweet> collector = new ArrayList<Tweet>(); collector.add(tweet); if (tweet.replies != null ) collect(tweet.replies, collector); The above code will collect all levels